# Read max value from CSV and write to new CSV

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have daily new CSV files, from these the maximum value must be read and the whole line of the maximum value must be written into a new CSV file. The maximum value can occur several times. The CSV files look like this and contain 1000+ rows:

```
"Series";"Time";"Value"
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:00";52
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:02";53
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:04";54
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:06";54
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:08";194
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 17:10";53
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 17:42";194
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 17:44";194
```

The result in the new csv file should look like this:

```
"Series";"Time";"Value"
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 01:08";194
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 17:42";194
"Total Session Number";"2020-01-14 17:44";194
```

I have been trying for almost a few weeks to find an example of how to do this, but without success. Maybe someone can help me with an example or a code that solves my problem?

Comment: Is your question that you would like help to look for an example?

Comment: My question is whether anyone can help me. With an example or with a code that solves my problem (if something like that already exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=C:\path\to\input.csv"
set "output=Z:\path\to\output.csv"
set lgr=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=;" %%i in ("%input%") do if %%i geq !lgr! set lgr=%%i
type "%input% | findstr /e "\"Value\" ;%lgr%"
```

Just change the file names `input.csv` and `input.csv` to your desired input and output file names.

How it works, it reads each line into metavariable `%%a` then splits the line by `;` and selects the 3rd token (number) and matches each to find the largest number. Once found, we type through the file specifically filtering for that number and redirect output to `new_csv.csv`

A few side notes!!
This will only work if the format is as per your given examples, if you have more semi colons, it will not work as this very specifically uses the 3rd token to do the math.

Lastly, if your number has any normal alphabetical character included, which is won't, it will not work.

Comment: Try again now. As @stephan commented we needed `delayedexpansion` in this instance.

Comment: I still have a small question: if I have a CSV like "Series"; "Time"; "Value"; "Number", do I only have to change 'Token=4' and 'echo "Series"; "Time"; "Value"; "Number"?

Comment: @angry_agent123: depends. Do you want the highest *Value* (Token 3) or the highest *Number* (token 4)? If it's "Value", then `findstr /e` won't work.
'